# How to calculate the volume and surface area of a sphere cap which has been cut by a plane parallel to its axis

Tags: geometry, spheres

Suppose I have a spherical cap, defined by known angle $\alpha$ and radius $R$, as shown in the left hand portion of the attached figure. Here is an image:

[image]

I am working on a project where the sphere cap is cut into two parts, by a plane parallel to the axis of symmetry of the sphere cap, at a distance $d$ from the axis - see right hand portion of the above figure.

If I then remove the region which is shaded the lighter colour blue (the $x>d$ region), how can I calculate the volume of the remaining darker blue region? Likewise, how about the surface area of the curved portion of the remaining region?

Many thanks in advance

(Image source: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html)

Comment: Do you know in principle how a volume can be calculated by integrating the areas of cross sections?

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen in principle, yes! I thought for the volume I could integrate across 'adding up' the cross sectional areas across the width of the cap. Each cross sectional area is the area of a circular segment $A(x) = 1/2 r(x)^2 (\theta - \sin\theta)$, according http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html.  However, I'm not sure how to find $r$, the radius of the circular segment at a given distance $x$ across the cap. Perhaps I am thinking about this in the wrong way though - any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to suggest. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested in your comment, the volume can be calculated as follows:
$$V=\int_{-a}^{d}A(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-a}^{d}r(x)^2(\theta(x)-\sin\theta(x))\,dx,
$$
where $r(x)$ is the radius of the intersection of the sphere with the plane with the given $x$-coordinate, and $\theta(x)$ is the angle corresponding to the cross-sectional circular segment.  You can find out $r(x)$ from the equation
$$r(x)^2=y^2+z^2,
$$
where $x,y,z$ satisfy the equation of the sphere. Once you know $r(x)$, you can use a formula from the MathWorld page to calculate $\theta(x)$. I am deliberately giving you just hints for now, as you will remember the answer better if you work for it, but I intend to turn this into a full answer later. Good luck!

Comment: I think I can write $r(x)^2 = R^2 - x^2$, and the width across each circular segment as $w(x) = 2 \sqrt{R^2 \cos^2 \alpha - x^2}$. Then the angle subtended is $\theta(x) = 2 \sin^{-1} \frac{w(x)}{2r(x)}$, as according to MathWorld. However, I then end up with a rather nasty looking integral! Computing this numerically using an integration function in Python, between $x=-R \cos\alpha$ and $x=R \cos\alpha$ (i.e. across the entire sphere cap) does give me the expected volume of a sphere cap, $V_{cap} =  1/3 \pi R^3 (2-3\sin\alpha + \sin(\alpha)^3))$ ...

Comment: ... however, I tried the same numerical approach to calculate the surface area. I integrated the arc length $s(x) = r(x) \theta(x)$, again between $x=-R \cos \alpha$ and $x = R \cos\alpha$. However, the computed answer was not equal to the surface area of a sphere cap, $2\pi R^2 (1-\sin\alpha)$. Therefore, I'm not sure whether I have made a mistake in my derivation, or if it is my computational method used to compute the integral which is causing my issues!

Comment: Yes, the volume calculation looks right. The integral is somewhat messy. As for the area, you cannot just integrate the arc length, as the area of a narrow strip between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$ is not necessarily close to $\Delta x$ times the length. Think of the area of the surface $0\le x\le 1$, $-1\le y\le 1$, $z=\sqrt{1-y^2}$. (Half a cylinder on its side.) Every strip parallel to the $x$-axis has length 1, and $\int_{-1}^{1}1\,dx=2$, but the area is $\pi$.

Comment: I think I've got it; I need to compute $S.A. =\int_{-a}^{d}r(x)\theta(x) ds$, where $ds$ is the differential element of length along the surface of the sphere cap, $ds = \sqrt{1 + (\frac{dz}{dx})^2} dx = \sqrt{ 1+\frac{x^2}{R^2-x^2}} dx = \frac{R}{r(x)} dx$. Then, my integral becomes  $S.A. =\int_{-a}^{d} R\,\theta(x) dx$, where I can compute $\theta(x)$ using the expressions for $r(x)$ and $w(x)$ above.