# Inverted arc length integration on a spherical section

Tags: integration, geometry, analysis, differential-geometry

I have a question for you about a problem resulting from a physics & heat conduction model where I am stuck on the geometrical modeling/solving part.

It's about the spherical cap of a horizontal tank, which I want to calculate the heat conduction for between discrete locations (see [Geometry Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oolIP.png)).
This is the equation I want to use for context (used eg. also for a frustum):

$$Q = \lambda \, A(x) \, \frac{dT}{dx} \; \; \; \to \; \; \;  Q = f(x_a,x_b,...)\; ? $$

(Variable & parameter names explained at the end)
I want to solve this so that I can get $Q$ for the different slices of the spherical section (eg. between the slices a and b).
As the slices are vertically sliced I am using $x$ as a vertical coordinate for the determination of the Area $A$ for the respective points, where for the cross-sectional area we have ([reference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html)):

$$r(x) = \sqrt{{R_d}^2 - x^2}$$
$$ A(x) = s(x) \, t =  r(x) \, \theta(x) \, t= \sqrt{{R_d}^2 - x^2} \; \; 2 \arccos \left( \frac{d}{\sqrt{{R_d}^2 - x^2}} \right) \, t $$

For the above equation this results in:

$$ Q = \lambda \, \sqrt{{R_d}^2 - x^2} \; \; 2 \arccos \left( \frac{d}{\sqrt{{R_d}^2 - x^2}} \right) \, t \, \frac{dT}{dx}$$
$$ \iff \frac{1}{\sqrt{{R_d}^2 - x^2} \, \arccos \left( \frac{d}{\sqrt{{R_d}^2 - x^2}} \right)} \, dx = \frac{2 \lambda t}{Q} \, dT$$
$$ \Rightarrow \int_{x_a}^{x_b} \frac{1}{\sqrt{{R_d}^2 - x^2} \, \arccos \left( \frac{d}{\sqrt{{R_d}^2 - x^2}} \right)} \, dx = \frac{2 \lambda t}{Q} \int_{T_a}^{T_b} dT $$

Now sadly I have no clue on how to get an analytical solution for the left side.
The area and volume of this kind of shape have been aided in other posts (posts [2635418](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635418/how-to-calculate-the-volume-and-surface-area-of-a-sphere-cap-which-has-been-cut) and [4482377](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482377/arc-lengths-of-parallel-sections-of-spherical-cap), which I am using already), but this results in an inverse integral of the area kind of.

Is there a sulution to this integral? Are there possibly other coordinates that I could do this in where we may get a solvable(?) integration or do I need to approximate my problem through eg. a taylor series at each point?

Many! thanks in advance for any hints or aid in this dead end for me.

($Q$ = Heat flow; $\lambda$ = Heat conductivity coefficient; $A(x)$ = Area; $T$ = Temperature; $x$ = vertical coordinate; $t$ = thickness (thin) of the tank wall; $R_d$ = Curvature radius of the dome; $d$ = cut distance from sphere center; $R_c$ = Radius of cylindrical section)

Comment: I would be shocked if there was a closed form for that left side. WA doesn't seem to find a closed form, as you can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+1%2F%28sqrt%28R%5E2-x%5E2%29arccos%28a%2Fsqrt%28R%5E2-x%5E2%29%29%29).

Comment: @Accelerator Yea, I checked it a lot on WA. This term and a slightly better term when going through one stage of substitution of the $sqrt(R_d^2-x^2)$. Nothing really worked.
But then also the solution for post # 4482377 the solution is also not from WA... So I still have _some_ hope... ^^

Comment: Okay, I follow you up through deriving the expression for $Q$. But then you toss in a $\iff$, and give an equation that would follow only if $Q = 1$. Why is $Q = 1$? And if $Q$ is constant, wouldn't $Q(x_a, x_b) = 0$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oh. Excuse that please. I forgot to carry the Q in my notes as well  to the right side, where it would reside for now until the integrals are solved. I hope that resolves your confusion?

Comment: Not really. By leaving $Q$ outside the integral, you are still assuming $Q$ is constant.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That's right. $Q$ is constant over $x$. Even though the area changes, the total heat flow stays constant over the observed distance (_not_ flux: $Q$ per area; that changes).

Comment: Then as Accelerator indicates, there likely isn't a closed-form expression for the integral. You could simplify the form with the substitution $u = \frac d{\sqrt{R_d^2 - x^2}}$, but it is not likely to lead to something useful. Hoever the lack of a closed form expression is not the major concern that most inexperienced students think it is. The integration is quite stable to calculate numerically except when $x \approx R_d$ (assuming $d$ is constant - though your description sound like it should be a function of $x$).

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yea. I will see how I can approximate the Integral for my purpose. 
For having a closed expression I tried doing a Taylor series around the middle in between each of my nodes and that worked surprisingly well for approximating it (comparing to numerical integration result in python). With just the second order Taylor series integrated that was at the worst around 0.3% inaccurate for my parameters.

Thank you very much for giving the problem a consideration!